# Inefficient Query Using REGEX

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regex-group

I am tyring to lookup other rows matching on certain phone number fields.  The problem is that the phone number fields are in inconsistent formats.  Some of them have (, ), and - and so do not.  I have the following query using REGEX, but it's taking an incredibly long time to run so I'm wondering if there's a better, more efficient way, to accomplish the same.  I'm not really that great at SQL or Postgres so thanks!

```
--Find Matching Accounts By Phone Number
select a.sfid as first_account, a2.sfid as second_account
from salesforce.account a
         join salesforce.account a2 on a2.sfid != a.sfid and
                                       ((REGEXP_REPLACE(a.phone, '\D', '', 'g') = REGEXP_REPLACE(a2.phone, '\D', '', 'g')) or
                                        (REGEXP_REPLACE(a.phone, '\D', '', 'g') = REGEXP_REPLACE(a2.alternate_phone__c, '\D', '', 'g')) or
                                        (REGEXP_REPLACE(a.phone, '\D', '', 'g') = REGEXP_REPLACE(a2.emergency_contact_phone__c, '\D', '', 'g')) or
                                        (REGEXP_REPLACE(a.phone, '\D', '', 'g') = REGEXP_REPLACE(a2.emergency_contact_phone_2__c, '\D', '', 'g')))
where a.cancellation_reason__c in (select distinct cancellation_reason__c from salesforce.account where cancellation_reason__c like '%Move%');
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to show what numbers you are formatting and how.

Comment: I'm formatting phone numbers like (801) 555-1234 as 8015551234.  I'm using the REGEX above to format.

Comment: Unfortunately the question was closed before I had a chance to share my answer. There's an obvious inefficiency that no optimizer is going to deal with very well - the `OR` conditions with your main join (I'd guess it would decide to do a nested loop table scan here - slow). You can make this easier by unpivotting out the possible columns and joining on that. My demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=754c43979086e93ea832349b92610132 I would also simplify the `cancellation_reason__c` filter - you don't need a subquery.

Comment: This has an entire working query, it doesn't seem to be lacking in clarity.  It could use an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) of the query, or an EXPLAIN if the former will never finish.